# a gui with java for an access database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

i have implement a gui with java for an access database my data is in arabic language of egypt when i type it in the gui it transmit it in the database with any letters like &&U..+==-- what should i do??

Answer (score 2):

Learn about UTF-8 and I18N.

You'll need to support it both in Java and in your database.